# What's the Maximum length for a registered COM Class?

Tags: com, assemblies, registry, com+

When objects get added to the Windows Registry, they show up like so:

```
MyNamespace.MyType
```

I seem to remember running into issues with my namespaces and classnames being too long when trying to register them for COM.  Is there a maximum length limitation in registering classes in Windows or COM+?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Have no more than 39 characters.
- Contain no punctuation (including underscores) except one or more periods.
- Not start with a digit.
- Be different from the class name of any OLE 1 application, including the OLE 1 version of the same application, if there is one.*

**[source = MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911706.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

The primary way to register COM components is by their CLSID, a fixed size 16 byte number.  A GUID.  You can publish a ProgID, that's useful to COM clients that need to use late binding.  Like scripting languages.

I have no idea if there's a length limit to ProgIDs, there isn't one defined in the COM infrastructure.  Maybe the scripting language has one.  I know you are using VB6, there's no need for a ProgID at all.  It prefers early binding (new ClassName, not CreateObject).  Which is a good idea because late bound calls are about 10,000 times slower.

Anyhoo, if you want to specify a ProgId then use the `<ProgId>` attribute.  The normal format is AppName.ClassName, something that should rarely test any kind of length limit.

Comment: I'm not sure where we found the length limit. It might have been when trying to create an ActiveX Component in VB6. Interestingly, we'll be creating a .NET component that will be both early bound in VB6 as well as late bound in a different solution that uses classic ASP/VB Script. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: ProgID's allow to use the latest version of a component, if multiple are installed. Late Binding is independent of creation through CLSID or ProgID. If performance is a concern, you can resolve it through `CLSIDFromProgID` before instantiating many objects.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of a random limit on the the "Programmatic ID"...

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic
---------------------------
Programmatic ID string too long '<<project_name>>.<<control_name>>'.
The Programmatic ID must be 39 characters or less.
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```